# Charting Required in DOJO - Google Finance like chart

Tags: javascript, graph, dojo

I need to make a graph which has the functionalities as the graph in

http://www.google.com/finance?q=INDEXDJX:.DJI,INDEXSP:.INX,INDEXNASDAQ:.IXIC

I need to make a graph which has zoom and pan options. But UNLIKE google maps, i want to load the data at runtime. For eg when I pan right, then only I want to load the data. I do not want to load all data before hand and then send it to the graph. I want to load data piece by piece, something like how google maps are loaded.

I do not want to use flash or JQUERY. DOJO is acceptable!

Thanks!

Comment: So what have you tried so far? Have a look at the [d3.js](http://d3js.org/) lib to draw graphs.

Comment: I am using Dojo Chart widgets. But its too painful to code all the pan functions to fetch new data from server. Whatever current implementations I have seen has to have all the data in the front end at the start

Comment: I agree with @Sirko.  I have done a little bit with the dojo charts, but if I had a new project that I was starting and it needed charts, I would look to use d3.

Answer (score 0):

What about [Google Visualization API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference)?

Have a look at the playground, the APIs offer the same graph as Google Finance. It's called Annotated Time Line (class `google.visualization.AnnotatedTimeLine`): http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#annotated_time_line

Comment: It uses flash. thanks anyway, but I do not want to use flash..

Comment: Sorry, I just did not assume Google would do it via flash in 2012.

Comment: I had the same reaction Zer0 did. I love the initial impression I saw from Google's Visualization API, but was disappointed to see flash as the result too.